# Print numbers on same line (Python)

Tags: python

I have a variable which give as output numbers taken from a list every loop.

```
idx = 0
for i in y:
        listbyte = subprocess.check_output('python foo.py ' + path + str(y[idx]), shell=True).rstrip()
        idx += 1
        listnum = listbyte.decode()
        number = (listnum[0])
        print(number)
        u.append(listnum)
```

If I print `number`, the output format is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I put `end = ''` at the end of the print, it works pretty well, outputing: `12345`.

The question is: how can I make this output a variable ? I have to use this format for some code ahead in the program but from what I see the `end = ''` argument is something restricted to `print()` function.

It should be something like this:

```
a = number(listnum[0])
print(a)

>>>12345
```

Thanks

EDIT: using Megabeets answer, the output now is:

```
0
09
091
0912
09126
091265
0912655
09126554
091265548
```

Comment: not a duplicate, the answer of that question doesn't apply to my problem..

Comment: Just create a string variable, perhaps accumulating the elements into a list and then using `''.join()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `a += (listnum[0])` as you can see in the following example:

```
a = ''
idx = 0
for i in y:
        listbyte = subprocess.check_output('python foo.py ' + path + str(y[idx]), shell=True).rstrip()
        idx += 1
        listnum = listbyte.decode()
        a += (listnum[0])
        u.append(listnum)
```

And then `a` will be a string which contains "12345"

```
>>> print(a)
12345
```

In case you want `a` to be an integer at the end, and not a string, you can parse it using `int(a)`

Comment: edited question after applying your answer. thanks, btw.

Comment: Don't print `a` in every iteration. Print it outside the loop, only after the `for`.

Comment: Printing out of the loop it gives error...From "a" I can't select to print only the last one ?

Comment: Notice how I gave up the `number` parameter. It is not required here. Try to copy and paste my code and then add `print (a)` after the loop.

Comment: If you have line breaks in the numbers use `strip`. For example `"5\n".strip()`

Comment: How we can talk in chat ? I would like to show you full code, maybe can be helpful..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156848/discussion-between-link-and-megabeets).

Answer (score 1):

You can either store the numbers in a `string` and convert that to `int` or append to a `list` and `join` them later on.

**Example** for a list of numbers from `[1,5]` :

Using a `list`,

```
>>> nums = []
>>> for i in range(1,6): 
        nums.append(i) 

>>> nums
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> ''.join(str(x) for x in nums)
=> '12345'
>>> int(''.join(str(x) for x in nums))
=> 12345
```

Using a `str`

```
>>> nums = ''
>>> for i in range(1,6): 
        nums+=str(i)

>>> nums
=> '12345'
>>> int(nums)
=> 12345
```

Or even do it without any conversions **mathematically**

```
>>> nums=0
>>> for i in range(1,6): 
        nums=(nums*10)+i 

>>> nums
=> 12345
```

Comment: The fact is that the numbers are coming with line-break, not in the same line and I can't control the way this works. They are coming from an array...
Your solutions sounds perfect for any other situation but not for mine, I guess...

Comment: @Link , instead of printing `number`, just *use* any of the above technique and then later on after the loop, `print` it. So for *example*, using `list`, instead of doing `print(number)`, do `nums.append(number)`  and then after the loop gets over, use the `join` function as I have shown to bring them together.

Answer (score 0):

print 5 % (101 % 3) and (76 // 3) * 4